# Resolve Spring injections for dependant jar in base Project

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am working on a project where we developed various jars as small modules. Then these jars were added as dependencies in a base project.

In the base projects applicationContext we have imported the applicationContext of all dependendant jars using the following line

```
<import resource="classpath*:applicationContext.xml" />
```

The above line makes sure that all the applicationContexts.xml s get loaded. On code analysis I found that each of the module in its applicationContext has the dataSource injected. Although all the jars are going to use the same datasource still each of the jar is instantiating its own datasource. Is there a way by which I can specify a global datasource which can be injected through base class itself.

In each of the jars we have a datasource injected which the jar uses to perform database operations. I would want the jars to use a datasource of base jar instead of its own datsources.

Comment: And where is this datasource defined? And how do you reference it in each applicationContext.xml file?

Comment: Although what I am about to say is probably not an option in your case, I have come to the conclusion that when you need a module to be reused by multiple different projects, it is rarely a good idea to have that module depend on Spring . It would be best if the module was spring agnostic, and then you could create a Spring configuration module which would be able to wire up all the dependencies for that projects that need it, using Java config. For customization of the configuration module you could use a combination of properties and abstract configuration classes